# How to express empty hash

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Is there any way to express the empty hash in Sorbet?

I have the attribute that has a well defined shape or is set to `{}`. Obviously `T.type_alias({})` won't work because `{}` works as the `Hash` which is translated to `T::Hash[T.untyped, T.untyped]`. The easiest solution would be to have something like `T.nil` and then use it as `T::Hash[String, T.nil]` (fetching the value for the non-existing key will always return a `nil` value), but there is no such construction.

The workaround is to change the code to not accept the empty hash there and handle it differently. Then, it is possible to have `T.nilable(SomeType)`. However, I would like to keep the code as it is now and just add a proper type signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `T::Hash[String, T.nilable(String)]`? However when I try on [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20%0A%20%20params(%0A%20%20%20%20h%3A%20T%3A%3AHash%5BString%2C%20T.nilable(String)%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20).void%0A%7D%0Adef%20try_hash(h)%0A%20%20h%5B1%5D%3B%0A%20%20T.reveal_type(h%5B'asdf'%5D)%0Aend%0A%0Atry_hash(%7B%7D)%0Atry_hash(%7B1%20%3D%3E%20'asdf'%7D)), it seems to indicate that it won't type-check arguments of the method correctly.

> I have the attribute that has a well defined shape

You may want to use [T::Struct](https://sorbet.org/docs/tstruct) to represent this. Sorbet doesn't have great support for [shape](https://sorbet.org/docs/shapes) yet.

> T.nil

You can use NilClass. It's actually a Ruby class.

Comment: You are completely right! How could I overlook the `NilClass`! It means that I can express the empty hash as `T::Hash[T.untyped, NilClass]` (It accepts hash with some `{foo: nil}` entries but it is fine in this case). Thanks!